# Photoshop Pen Tool fills outside of path

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pen-tool

When using the Pen Tool in shape mode, the shape is filled outside of the path instead of the inside. How do I make the Pen Tool fill the inside?

[image]

Comment: Why do you have like a bazillion anchors?  Is that really necessary? Haven't you learnt you to create Bézier curves with the pen tool?  Anyhoo, I can't replicate your problem - it's probably some option you've accidentally hit in the Pen Tool. If all else fails, reset Photohops's preferences to default.

Comment: Problemdescription and Solution here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XgWDF1LWhis

Answer (score 8):

With the Pen Tool selected, or an existing shape or path selected with a Selection Tool, change the Path Operation to **Combine Shapes**.

[image: Path Operations]

Comment: This option is already selected..
that's the problem..

Comment: I'm not sure there's anything else that can cause whats happening. Could you share a full screenshot with the path selected maybe?

Comment: sometimes you have to switch to one of the other modes and it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you right click on the path and click "fill path", the dialogue box pops up. There is an option under "blending" called mode. Switch that from "normal" to "behind".

problem solved!

Answer (score -2):

Solved it!

I don't know why but when I set it up to "combine shapes" it suddenly worked.

[image]